# I would like to enter 2 dates in the Where condition, once for August and once for October

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I would like to enter 2 dates in the Where condition, once for August and once for October. Unfortunately I don't get any further here, because I can only enter a date (from .. to) in the Where condition see AND date between.

```
SELECT
  subregion1_code,
  subregion1_name,
  SUM(new_confirmed) as august_confirmed,
  SUM(new_tested) as august_tested,
  SUM(new_confirmed) as october_confirmed,
  SUM(new_tested) as october_tested,
  SUM(new_confirmed) / SUM(new_tested) AS positive_test_rate, 
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.covid19_open_data.covid19_open_data` as B
WHERE
  country_code = "US"
  AND aggregation_level = 1
  AND date BETWEEN '2020-10-01' AND '2020-10-30'
 
GROUP BY
  subregion1_code,
  subregion1_name 
ORDER BY
  positive_test_rate DESC
```

Comment: Does `date` is column name?

Comment: is it always 2 month prior from the selected date that you want?

Comment: @Akina ye s it is

Comment: @nbk No, I would like a column for August (as august_confirmed, august_tested) and a column for October (october_confirmed, october_tested) but should be in one code

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
  subregion1_code,
  subregion1_name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 8 THEN new_confirmed ELSE 0 END) AS august_confirmed,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 8 THEN new_tested ELSE 0 END) AS august_tested,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 10 THEN new_confirmed ELSE 0 END) AS october_confirmed,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 10 THEN new_tested ELSE 0 END) AS october_tested,
  SUM(new_confirmed) / SUM(new_tested) AS positive_test_rate, 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.covid19_open_data.covid19_open_data` AS B
WHERE
  country_code = 'US'
  AND aggregation_level = 1
  AND (date BETWEEN '2020-10-01' AND '2020-10-31' OR date BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-31')
GROUP BY subregion1_code, subregion1_name 
ORDER BY positive_test_rate DESC
```

Comment: But that applies to both August and October, but I want a "Where condition" for October and another for September

Comment: *I would like to enter 2 dates in the Where condition, once for August and once for October.* September or October? Also: `SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 8 THEN new_confirmed ELSE 0 END)` returns the sum for August ONLY and `SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 10 THEN new_confirmed ELSE 0 END)`  returns the sum for October ONLY.